# Reset Node of ModelInstance

Tags: android, libgdx, blender

I have a g3db file from blender containing stack of cards. It contains animation of top card moving from above to below.
After the animation completes I want to reset the Card Node to its previous position. How can I achieve that?

I tried saving the initial Transform value of ModelInstance and applying after the node animation completes.I also tried saving the globalTransform and localTransform values of card Node and applying after animaton completes.

But nothing seems to work. Please give me some suggestions for achieving this.

Comment: if you have an animation to card draw, you can make an new action called idle with 1 frame, or re set the draw animation and pause it on the first frame.

Comment: @Hllink Reset animation worked. Thanks.